# Getting mapreduce.task.partition in CDH4

Tags: c++, hadoop

With CDH4/hadoop-2.0.0 I am running into an issue wherein a pipes program is erroring out when it tries to get a task's partition:

```
Hadoop Pipes Exception: Key mapreduce.task.partition not found in JobConf
```

This worked just fine with 0.21 and I was wondering how the same result can be achieved with 2.0.0. Any help would be much appreciated.

PS: I tried toying with [hadoop pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624732/hadoop-pipes-example-fails-with-cdh4-hadoop-2-0-0) to try and debug this. But ran into a wall there as well. *sigh*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides shipping with [YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html), CDH4 includes hadoop-0.20 which uses the key `mapred.task.partition` instead of `mapreduce.task.partition`(from 0.21). Changing it back to the former fixed my problem.